# Problem generating code from Swagger file for ValueTuple

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger, openapi-generator

I have a swagger json file and the API is built with NET7. The API exposes NET-specific types such as `ValueTuple`. When I try to generate the code, the type is generate like:

> "System.ValueTuple`2[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]": {
> "type": "object",
> "additionalProperties": false
> }

Is this correct? Is it possible to make it cleaner?